80s/90's Sci-fi movie about gambling with blue liquid that creates life and makes it longer
I just recalled another gem from my childhood. It's a movie where people gamble by playing games against each other where the winner gets the opponent's blue liquid.
The blue liquid is something that creates life and the loser in this case gets the blue liquid extracted from them, which kills them and leaves only ashes. Others are betting their blue liquid on the competitors. 
I suspect the movie was in English, but I saw it with dubbing so can't say for sure. I guess it was American or European made.

I think you're after sci-fi film Timemaster from 1995 with Pat Morita and a young Michelle Williams. From an online synopsis:

The world has been destroyed by some sort of disaster, and the few remaining survivors are living in a "Mad Max" type of world, where they camp out in the ruins to defend themselves from raiders. [...] a group of aliens play games that affect the past, present, and future destiny of the universe. The aliens send "collectors" through space and time to planets where there are life forms to collect them as contestants or actually pawns for these virtual reality games, since the contestants really do not have free will over the outcomes. [...] The aliens bet on the outcome of these games with "blue", the distilled [liquid] substance of eternal life which is extracted from the losers of the game.

Here's one of these games, where the blue liquid (which is a life extender) is extracted from the loser in the end and he turns into a  skeleton:




The video isn't showing up for me btw.
